# I can only log into my site after going to a blocked page and getting redirected?

Tags: php, session, authentication

Anytime i try to log in from just /login it submits and redirects me to the home page as it so post to but doesn't store the session even though the user/pass combo was correct but if i go to /private and get redirected back to /login and login it store the session

login.php

```
require("includes/connection.php");
$page ='/login.php';
require("includes/logs/log.php");
require("includes/update_session.php");

if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
      echo '<script>window.location = "/index.php";</script>';
      die("Redirecting to index.php");
}
$submitted_username = '';

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $query = "SELECT id,username,password,salt,email
              FROM users
              WHERE username = :username";

    $query_params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $login_ok = false;

    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO CSD_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS (id) VALUES (:id)";

        $query_params = array(':id' => $row["id"]);

        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        }

        if($check_password === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    if($login_ok) {
        unset($row['salt']);
        unset($row['password']);

        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
        session_write_close();
        echo '<script>window.location="/index.php";</script>';
        die("Redirecting to: index.php");
    } else {
        print("Login Failed.");
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <?php
  require("includes/scripts.php");
  ?>
</head>

<body><center>
  <div id="pagewidth">
    <?php
    require("includes/header.php");
    ?>

    <div id="content">
      <section class="row">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" class='form'>
          Username:<br />
          <input style='text-align: center' type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" />
          <br /><br />
          Password:<br />
          <input style='text-align: center' type="password" name="password" value="" />
          <br /><br />
          <button type="submit" value="Login" class='btnSmall grey'>Login</button>
        </form><br>
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
      </section>
      <section class="row grey">

      </section>
    </div>
    <?php
    include("includes/footer.php");
    ?>
  </div>
</center></body>
</html>
```

Comment: confused why you are using javascript to redirect when you can just header('Location: --chosen url--  ');

Comment: for some reason that would not redirect which could be part of the error??

Comment: what's the full url of the page you want to redirect to?

Comment: Could it be that the first thing you do is `if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) redirect` so if you are already logged in it sends you to `index.php` Make sure you are logged out and try again

Comment: just take off the ! from > if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) as stated above.

Comment: Also hash your passwords using `password_hash()` and check them using `password_verify()` Dont do it manually

Comment: @Juakali92 **That would mean you could never login** _I think_

Comment: but I'm not logged in because when you're logged in things change but it stays as if you're not logged in

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah i misread it, only very briefly looked at it. Ignore me

Comment: `65536` rounds on the hashing algorithm???? Are you protecting the national debt or something? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634968/i-can-only-log-into-my-site-after-going-to-a-blocked-page-and-getting-redirected#comment58952043_35634968 Overkill or what

Comment: @Juakali92 Ignore you! Never!! None of us are perfect. Just thought I had better point it out to the questioner

Comment: @RiggsFolly why would i take out the ! because that would show that that the user is not empty so they are already logged in???

Comment: I did not suggest that! Juakali suggested that, and I disagreed with him/her I suggest you look at your code and fix it so it makes sence

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you have

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
```

basically stating, IF the user variable is NOT EMPTY (they ARE logged in), redirect to login. You probably want to have the below instead.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
```

You want to ask someone to login only if they are not logged in, right?

Comment: not correct this is my log in page i do not want users to be there if they are already logged in if the session is not empty redirect to the home page

Comment: "session_write_close() Ends the current session and stores session data. Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close()"


Have you tried removing session_write_close()?

Comment: I can try that but why would it let me login if i am redirected from another page???

Comment: We're developers, here. No one knows how anything works, we just smash our faces against the keyboard until we get a green light.

Comment: Still doesn't work and the redirect is to the index page if the user is logged in that is not the issue